# How to create a RESTful client on Google App Engine?

Tags: java, json, google-app-engine, rest, client

I'm trying to create a RESTful web service client on Google App Engine (Java) that consumes Json. I've tried Sitebricks and Jersey, but neither of them seem to work. Is there any framework out there that can be used to create RESTful web service clients on GAE?

Exception for Sitebricks:

```
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:366)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:555)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(DevAppServerFactory.java:283)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkAccess(DevAppServerFactory.java:308)
    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.checkAccess(ThreadGroup.java:315)
    at java.lang.Thread.init(Thread.java:376)
    at java.lang.Thread.<init>(Thread.java:525)
    at com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClientConfig$Builder$2.newThread(AsyncHttpClientConfig.java:421)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.<init>(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:598)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:913)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1336)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:132)
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.jdk.JDKAsyncHttpProvider.execute(JDKAsyncHttpProvider.java:156)
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.jdk.JDKAsyncHttpProvider.execute(JDKAsyncHttpProvider.java:123)
    at com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClient.executeRequest(AsyncHttpClient.java:496)
    at com.google.sitebricks.client.AHCWebClient.simpleRequest(AHCWebClient.java:85)
    at com.google.sitebricks.client.AHCWebClient.get(AHCWebClient.java:133)
```

And for Jersey:

```
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("javax.xml.bind.JAXBPermission" "setDatatypeConverter")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:366)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:555)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(DevAppServerFactory.java:283)
    at javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.setDatatypeConverter(DatatypeConverter.java:134)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$3.run(JAXBContextImpl.java:304)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$3.run(JAXBContextImpl.java:303)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:302)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1170)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:145)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:248)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:235)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:432)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:637)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:584)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractJAXBProvider.getStoredJAXBContext(AbstractJAXBProvider.java:194)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractJAXBProvider.getJAXBContext(AbstractJAXBProvider.java:187)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractJAXBProvider.getUnmarshaller(AbstractJAXBProvider.java:139)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractJAXBProvider.getUnmarshaller(AbstractJAXBProvider.java:122)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractRootElementProvider.readFrom(AbstractRootElementProvider.java:111)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:565)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:517)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:684)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.get(WebResource.java:191)
```

Comment: It appears that you might be missing a credential authentication step prior to issuing your "GET" request.  You will probably need to establish a session by logging in to the service first.  Set your authentication model and credentials on the client prior to issuing the GET.

Comment: I followed http://tugdualgrall.blogspot.com/2010/02/create-and-deploy-jax-rs-rest-service.html and it worked for me without any issues.

Comment: @LarryHector No that's not it, it worked perfectly without authentication on a plain Jetty. The AccessControlExceptions are due to sandbox restrictions in AppEngine.

Comment: @Devashish That article describes how to create a web service server, I need a web service client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [google-api-java-client](http://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/wiki/JSON)?

At some level all you need is the ability to make HTTP requests and parse the response as JSON. What features are you looking for beyond that that make Jersey/Sitebricks more attractive to you?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I didn't know about google-http-java-client. I will check it out. I need SSL support and I was using Sitebricks already for serving HTML pages and RESTful web services.

Answer (score -1):

Try [jello-framework](http://jello-framework.com). It lets you expose your data model via RESTful (OData) service and it provides UI views out-of-the-box so you can test your application and start interacting with the data instantly.

Disclosure - I am the creator of Jello framework. Nevertheless, I decided to add it as a valid answer for RESTful client on GAE as it can provide a good solution for the asked question.

Comment: Hi @bummi, you are right, I should add a disclosure (which I just did). However, the fact that I am affiliated with jello-framework should not affect the validity of the answer as long as it answer the question.